# My code doesnt work for big numbers

Tags: c++, c, math

look , that code above is for calculate the sum of the prime numbers below 2000000 , but its not giving the correct answer but when i try to sum the prime numbers below 10, or 20 its gave the right answer , can anyone help me to discover whats is going on!?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){

    unsigned int ref = 0, m,divisoes = 0 , total = 0,flag = 2;
    unsigned int soma =0;

    while(ref < 9999999999999){
        ref = (flag * 2)-1;
        m = ceil(sqrt(ref));
        while( m > 2){
            if(ref % m == 0)
                divisoes++;
            m--;            
        }
        if(divisoes == 0){
            if( ref > 2000000) // limitador
             break;
            printf("%d \n",ref);
            soma += ref;
            total ++;
        }
        divisoes = 0;
        flag ++;    
    }
    // somando mais 2 , por que dois é o unico numero primo par.
    soma +=2;
    total++;
    printf("Soma %d , Total de Primos %d",soma,total);
    return 0;


}
```

Comment: The largest value an unsigned int can hold is 4294967295. If one is added to that, it becomes 0 (overflow).

Comment: @Steve: The largest value an `unsigned int` can hold depends on the implementation. The upper bound is at least `65535`, but it's typically `4294967295` (2**32-1)` on 32-bit and 64-bit systems.

Comment: For this particular problem, a 32-bit integer is not big enough, but a 64-bit integer is. `long long` is guaranteed to be at least 64 bits (and is exactly 64 bits on every implementation I've seen).

Comment: your program doesn't look any like C++, you should remove that tag. They're different languages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`9999999999999` is quite a bit larger than the maximum value of `unsigned int` (2^32 - 1).  A simple fix could be to add `ULL` suffix to all literals and switch `unsigned int` to `unsigned long long`.

Comment: I break the loop with the if( ref > 2000000) // limitador , and also i reduce the number from that big to 3000000 , and still not working.

Comment: Well i changed the unsigned int tp unsigned long long , still not working

Comment: @AngeloBerzacola What result are you getting, and what are you expecting?

Comment: 1,179,908,154 right is 142,913,828,922

Comment: As mentioned, `1179908154` can be stored in an `unsigned int`. `142913828922` cannot.  In fact, 142913828922 % (2^32) = 1179908154.  Switch to `unsigned long long` and it should work.

Comment: Maybe be this part are not showing the correct value:

`printf("Soma %u , Total de Primos %d",soma,total);`

is that right to show `unsigned long long`

Comment: You must use `%llu` to print unsigned long long int instead of `%u`

Answer (score 0):

Numeric data types have a certain amount of storage in memory to work with, after a certain value they [overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow).

You can think of this as an odometer on a car rolling over after it hits too many miles. You can use a larger [data type](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_data_types.htm) and it might support your needs. At some point numbers get large enough you need a library for arbitrary length numbers. Googling 'c++ BigInteger' will yield good results for you.

Answer (score 0):

The int datatype can store only (2^32-1) and your number is bigger then that... 
Use unsigned long so it can store long numbers.
.
You van also use unsigned float or unsigned double for big floating point values.